# Google Map alternatives with offline navigation support

Tags: google-play-store, google-maps, offline-map

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [alternatives to Google Maps](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1389/alternatives-to-google-maps)

Hi All,

Does google map application provides voice guided navigation ? Does it supports offline navigation ? Any app which supports offline/hybrid (like nokia ovi maps) mode of map navigation ? Any google map alternatives in android market ?

Thanks,

Ankur Shah

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1389/alternatives-to-google-maps

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/227/what-replacements-are-available-for-google-maps

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/591/gps-offline-application-for-android-download-maps-by-city-or-area

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1624/offline-map-for-android

Comment: Yes, Google Maps (more accurately Navigation) provides voice-guided navigation. It's one of the strongest selling points of the OS, after all.

Comment: Google Maps Voice-guided navigation is only available in a handful of countries, It is not available where I live in New Zealand. Google has had plenty of time to fix this and it has not. The same is true for google voice.

Comment: Google Maps is available in practically all countries. Google Maps Navigation is only available in some. And AFAIK, Google Voice Navigation is only on US so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used it, but here's one: [OsmAnd](http://www.appbrain.com/app/osmand/net.osmand)

> Open-source OSM-based GPS app with
>   online/offline capabilities and
>   audible navigation.
>
> - Online: maps, routing, search, edit OSM POI/bugs.
> - Offline: search POI, address, transport, map cache.