# Offline city map with directions and public transport?

Tags: google-maps, maps

I'm looking for an app which basically is google maps but completely offline. Even with the new feature of offline maps, the directions and the public transport don't work, as well as the street names are not shown.

Is there a real offline alternative to Google maps?

Comment: Closely related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2109/google-map-alternatives-with-offline-navigation-support

Comment: Cross posted? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871887/is-there-an-offline-city-gps-with-directions-and-public-transport?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter

Comment: No, not related. I'm looking spetially for the public transport functionallity, I already have the offline maps with another gps app.
Edit: yes, cross posted, I was told to post it here.

Comment: Please delete your other question on Stackoverflow then. [OSMAnd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Anvisics) is btw. also a viable free&open source alternative well worth a check (it has a free version with map download count limited to 16 or so). In urban areas it's often much more detailed than Gmaps and it has car/bicycle/walk routing modes and many other features. It's based on http://www.osm.org maps

Answer (score 1):

A quick google-fu, which took less than 2 seconds yielded this [hit](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/top-3-free-offline-gps-apps-android/) where I got the information from, fyi - keywords without quotes "*android gps offline maps*"

Possibly two that might be of interest -

[NavFree](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.navfree.android.OSM.ALL)

> Navfree is a completely free navigation app that offers turn-by-turn
>   directions, spoken and on-screen instructions, offline map use and
>   address search and live search via Google and Microsoft Bing, among
>   many other features. The maps it uses are available for free download
>   from the Navfree Store. The map data is stored on your device so there
>   is no need for a constant data connection while driving. It also
>   allows you to browse maps anytime, anywhere without paying for data
>   connections, which means no costly roaming charges when abroad.

[MapDroyd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.osa.android.mapdroyd) used to be another option, but it [was abandoned and has now been removed](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/MapDroyd).

> MapDroyd features world-wide off-line maps powered by OpenStreetMap. Experience true unplugged vector maps avoiding expensive network connections.

Apparently, there's a way to do this - as documented over on [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1412755) which enables you to create your offline maps for storage and to be used by the likes of Google Maps etc... Hope it helps! :)

Comment: I really recommend to check [OSMAnd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Anvisics), it's getting better with each version (it's completely free software!)

Comment: 'Limitations of Osmand Free - limited number of map downloads; no access to Wikipedia offline POIs' .. not exactly free, there's a paid version as well [OSMAnd+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.osmand.plus)

Comment: It's open source, I didnt mean free as in beer :-)  and it needs funding http://code.google.com/p/osmand/ If you want to sideload unrestricted versions, there are nightlies/ You can also compile it  yourself.

Comment: ahhh .... that's important sentence 'free as in beer' :) cool. will check it out! :) Cheers mate! :D