# How can I store my Google maps (and maybe directions) offline when previewing directions?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-navigation

I want to ask directions when I have a Wifi connections, then preview the route and store the maps offline for the entire route - so that when I'm underway I can just let GPS pick up my location and show me a map (and preferably the directions).

[I can store single maps if I'm not in directions preview](https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/3246076?hl=en&ref_topic=3499974), but can I do it **while I'm previewing directions**?

I found [these](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27236/offline-city-map-with-directions-and-public-transport) posts [with](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1624/is-there-an-offline-maps-application-for-android) many [alternatives](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/591/how-to-use-gps-maps-without-an-internet-connection) but first I'm looking for a solution in the [Google Maps app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps) itself.

Comment: What did you end up using?

Comment: @Baruch I did not find a solution using Google Maps and have switched to [Osmand Maps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.osmand&hl=en), a completely off-line solution. The free version limits the number of map updates you can do, I have not gotten around yet to paying for the full version (but intend to). It's worth it, although the interface is a bit complex and the precision not as good as Google - well, actual door-to-door precision is not necessary for the casual user.

Comment: I updated to the paid version (several years ago), *and* the interface has improved significantly in the meantime.