# Software for offline pedestrian navigation in New York

Tags: navigation, maps

My fiancée is going on a trip to New York City and she'd like to have some kind of navigation there on her G1/Dream.

Is there a software (preferably free, or not too costly), that would allow me to save the street map of the whole city (or state) to the SD card and do offline navigation for walking around during the visit? I suppose there should be something that uses OpenStreetMap that might even be free.

Comment: See also these previous questions about offline maps and GPS apps http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1624/offline-map-for-android and http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/591/gps-offline-application-for-android-download-maps-by-city-or-area

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Maps 5.0 has an [offline mode](http://www.eweek.com/c/a/Mobile-and-Wireless/Google-Maps-50-for-Android-Has-3D-Offline-Perks-499272/) that will allow you to view maps without an internet connection.

> Google is now caching large areas on Android devices based on what areas they frequently search in Google Maps from their Android phone or tablet. This means people living in New York City, for example, will always have local street and area Maps content.

But if that is not satisfactory, there is always [MapDroyd](http://www.mapdroyd.com/):

> MapDroyd stores map files locally on your device using our highly compressed and efficient MicroMap format which is designed and optimized for embedded devices.

Comment: +1 for MapDroyd, but
cmiiw, but for Google Maps, it sounds like you can't choose which locations are cached, it only cache the areas that you access the most (automatically). Since his fiancee is not from NYC most likely NYC is not what she access the most.

Answer (score 3):

OsmAnd is the perfect software for this. I just had to download it from Market, then download New York maps from the app, and then disable the internet connection from settings.

MapDroyd did the same, though, after I checked it out.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these two transit map apps:

[NYCMate](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.densebrain.android.nycsubwaymap) and [NYC Bus & Subway Map](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.episode6.android.nycsubwaymap)

Both include bus maps for each borough which are detailed enough to get you around and incredibly useful if you find you've walked too far and you really want to sit your way back home.