# Does Wifi P2P require *both* android devices to be 4.0+?

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-direct

According to the [android developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html)...

> "Wi-Fi peer-to-peer (P2P) allows Android 4.0 (API level 14) or later
>   devices with the appropriate hardware to connect directly to each
>   other via Wi-Fi without an intermediate access point"

Does this mean that both devices need to be 4.0+, or can one be a 4.0 device while the other is a (rooted) 2.x device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Normal WiFi" and "WiFi direct" are separate things. If you want to use the latter, the answer is yes: both devices must be supporting it. If, on the other hand, your question is whether there's a way to directly connect the two: there's always the "hotspot" feature, which was introduced already before 4.0. So one device (supporting this) could act as a WiFi hotspot, and the other could connect there as to any other WiFi router.

Comment: Can this be done even if there's no connection between the device acting as a hotspot and the internet (either through cellular or wifi)?  I want to be able to communicate between the two devices offline.

Comment: Should be possible – though I've never tried. You could raise that as a separate question, though (after having checked it hasn't been asked already). And here's your candidate: [Can my phone act as WiFi Access Point while Disabling Celluar Radio?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/98468/16575) asks for more or less the same.